# How do I get back all the original leading and trailing spaces I removed from using .trim?

Tags: java

I made a string into `.trim()`. I wanted to try and reverse it, but I can't seem to do it.

For example,

```
String a = "    apple     ";
```

I did, `a = a.trim();` such that:

```
assert(a == "apple");
```

I want to be able to get back to the original padded text.

```
assert( a == "    apple     ");
```

Comment: If you trim it the spaces are gone. If you want to know what it was before, then you should not overwrite it. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 3):

You cant unless you store the original string and go back to it.

```
String original = "    apple   ";
String backup = original;
string original = original.trim();
System.out.println(original); //this will show trimmed text
original = backup;
System.out.println(original); //this will show the original untrimmed text.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "get them back", but you can record them before you trim them.

You can find the index of the first non-removed character in the string as follows, based on the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--):

```
int k = 0;
while (k < string.length() && string.charAt(k) <= 0x20) {
  ++k;
}
```

Now, the leading whitespace is the string `string.substring(0, k)`.

You can do similarly to find the last non-removed character index (call it `m`); then the trailing whitespace is given by `string.substring(m+1)`.

And now that you've done this, there's no point in using `trim()`: `string.substring(k, m+1)` is your trimmed string (provided you have taken care of the "everything in the string is whitespace" case).